# Native library build path variables in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, buildpath

I have shared eclipse projects that use a build path variable as a relative location for jar dependencies.  So in the build path they appear as `VARIABLENAME/subdirectory/blah.jar`.  All developers have to do is define one variable in their workspace and all the projects build paths work.

The problem is that some of those jars also require the "Native Library Location" to be set.  The DLLs are typically in the same location that the jar was in, but I cannot figure out a way to use `VARIABLENAME` to reference the dlls location.  Everything is relative to this variable, developers should only have to set this one variable instead of grinding out a huge User Library definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your projects' launch configurations you can always (assuming a java application type of run/debug config), in the arguments tab, you can always add a line in the bottom textarea (vmargs)

-Djava.library.path=VARIABLENAME/subdirectory

assuming this is where your JNI libs are.  The VARIABLENAME can be defined through the "variables..." (either as en env_var if you also define it as an environment variable or redefining the variable "edit...").

Comment: +1 I considered this approach, I was worried eclipse might already be using java.library.path or something and that I would cause more problems that way.  I will give this a try then, another approach I have considered is have a build step (ant) copy them into the workspace or something.

Comment: eclipse has its own way of using the java.library.path system property.  One way it is accessible is to edit the eclipse.ini and sticking the setting after the -vmargs line.

Comment: Accepting answer, developers already have an env_var defined, so this seems to be my best option.